# How can I wrap each bash command's output in a single blank newline before and after?

Tags: bash, parsing, user-interface, unix, newline

How can I wrap bash command output so that it is surrounded on top and bottom with a blank newline?

I have trouble picking out the current command's output from the previous command and the next prompt. I've tried `PROMPT_COMMAND=echo` but this only adds a newline at the end and not the beginning. How can I have both so I can better parse my bash reality?

For example right now I see this:

```sh
rjurney$ ls ~/tmp/
total 312
-rw-r--r--   1 rjurney  staff    472 Mar 27 16:40 README.md
rjurney$
```

I want to see the following:

```sh
rjurney$ ls ~/tmp/

total 312
-rw-r--r--   1 rjurney  staff    472 Mar 27 16:40 README.md

rjurney$
```

Thanks!

Comment: you mean without calling a specific function like `addFeed ls /tmp` ?

Comment: @OznOg Yes, I want it to just magically happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash 4.4 introduced [PS0](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior).

To accomplish a blank line before and after each command, you can set `PS0` and `PS1` as:

```
PS0="
"
PS1="
$PS1"
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly I want to run these commands:

`export PS0="\n"`
`export PS1="\n$PS1"`


And then I can run `ls` and it will be surrounded by newlines? This does not work, I get two newlines at the end and none at the start.

Ah ha - bash is version 3.3.56 - thanks

Comment: Ok, even on bash 5 this doesn't prepend a CR :(

Comment: Don't know what's different about your environment but those commands work for me with 4.4.19(1)-release and 5.0.0(1)-release

Comment: These commands work for me on Ubuntu Linux 18.04/bash 4.4.19(1) but not on OS X 10.14.4/bash 4.4.19(1). Interesting.

Comment: Ok, my issue was that Hyper terminal ignores the standard settings for shells and relies on settings.json 'shell' entry. Replacing that with the upgraded 5.x shell in `/usr/local/homebrew/bin/bash` and applying your solution results in what I wanted.

Thanks!